# Save images via Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, images

I can save images from other sites on chrome browser but cannot do it on Facebook. Does it contains any JavaScript which block saving images?

How to save them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way. 
Go to the photo > Click "View Full size" > Then click and hold on the photo, where you'll get an pop-up asking to Save image,Open in new tab...etc

Comment: Thank you! Just an addendum for "dumb" people like me. "View full size" is at the end of the picture post, just before the comments. So you problably will have to scroll down to see it

Answer (score -1):

type in address 'mbasic.facebook.com' and you will be able to save images.